Function in LibreOffice Calc
How do I find the number of factors of a positive integer in LibreOffice Calc? For example, suppose the integers are in A-cells and I want to print the number of factors of them in the B-cells.

Please Edit and show examples of the inputs and expected answers.

Write a user-defined function. It shouldn't be hard — loop from 1 to the number and if number Mod i = 0 then increment the number of factors. If you get stuck then post the code you've tried along with any error message or unexpected behavior.

What is "Libre office Calculator", or "LibreOffice Calculator"? Do you mean LibreOffice Calc? Please edit to clarify.

@DrMoishePippik: Clearly the poster is referring to Calc — that's what the tag says, and the reference to cells in [columns] A and B remove all doubt.

@ReddyLutonadio: Seems clear enough to me. For example, if a positive integer 4 is in cell A1, then B1 should contain 3, because 4 has 3 factors: 1, 2, and 4. Is there any other way of interpreting the question as posted?

@JimK That is exactly my question.

@DrMoisePippik I have edited it now.

To follow up on @Jim K's comment, you only need to loop from 1 to half the number, since no factor of a number is greater than half of it, except for itself, so however many factors the loop to 1/2 comes up to, add 1 and you have all the factors. This saves you 1/2 the processing time, not a big deal for small numbers but can make a big difference for large ones.
